# Issue creating database file with Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, entity-framework-6

I have an issue that I just can't seem to find a solution for, so far everything seems to point to a SQL Server and very few examples or solutions that I have found deal with the actual creation of the file itself.

I have a database created, which I have been using for testing purposes with a code first approach, which I used VS to create the models from the database. In my testing I know wanted to get into testing with the file not being there and getting the application to create the database file.

in my app.config I have the following

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v13.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
      <connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyDbConnectionString" connectionString="data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Database\Test.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I have a file called MyDbContext which I have tried putting a few things to no avail.

```
        public MyDBContext() : base("name=MyDbConnectionString")
        {

            Database.SetInitializer<MyDBContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyDBContext>());
            //using (var context = new MyDBContext())
            //{
            //    context.Database.Initialize(force: true);
            //}
        }
        public virtual DbSet<ACCOUNTLIST_V1> ACCOUNTLIST_V1 { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And of course my model is very simple, which works if I manually use SQL Server Object Explorer to create a database. But once I remove the database and connection string and try to get the application to create the database, it actually fails with a message saying the database file Test.mdb doesn't exist.

I am now at a loss to understand what part of the step I am missing now.

Comment: Ok, I think I see the issue. I just don't know how to fix it. If I change the connection string in App.config to say f:\Test.mdb then the program runs and works.

It is obvious it doesn't like |DataDirectory|

So, my next question would be how do I go about setting the connection string, when this is going to be a UWP application?

Comment: I think localdb will not work with UWP, you need SQL Express with TCP sockets capabilities enabled. Localdb uses named pipes.

Comment: Embeded Db's do work, I just don't know how to do the connect string for it.

From what I have read UWP got support for embeded Db;s in 6.1 or 6.2 EF6

Comment: But localdb is not an embedded database!

Comment: Like I said, I connected the database file in Visual Studio and used the code first to create the models and that was what Visual Studio created for me and as you can see it also points to a database file. I am new to this, rather than say that. How about explaining to me how to fix it as that is what my question is.